# How to get text inside an inline-block element to ident?

Tags: css

Put simply, the checkboxes here are graphical as I do not want to use a checkbox element for accessibility reasons (only the link should respond to interactions).

But having a span next to an href and getting the text to indent to be aligned with the start of the text seems to be quite a challenge. 
Here's the [`Codepen`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdjypO):

```css
ul { 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #fffaaa;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

span.facetapi-check-active {
  background-image: url('https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/Very-Basic-Checked-checkbox-icon.png');
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="facetapi-check-active"></span>
    <a href="#" class="facetapi-inactive" id="facetapi-link-12">North West & Other Areas</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="facetapi-check-active"></span>
    <a href="#" class="facetapi-inactive" id="facetapi-link-13">Yorkshire and the Humber</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CSS tables**

```css
ul { 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #fffaaa;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: table;
}

span.facetapi-check-active {
  background-image: url('https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/Very-Basic-Checked-checkbox-icon.png');
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  display: table-cell;
}

a {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="facetapi-check-active"></span>
    <a href="#" class="facetapi-inactive" id="facetapi-link-12">North West & Other Areas</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="facetapi-check-active"></span>
    <a href="#" class="facetapi-inactive" id="facetapi-link-13">Yorkshire and the Humber</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```